# Unit cubes intersecting ball/sphere of radius $R$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, limits

Let $b(R)$ and $s(R)$ be the number of integer unit cubes intersecting the ball and sphere of radius $R$ centered at the origin in $\mathbb{R}^2$, respectively. Find $\lim_{R \to \infty} \frac{s(R)^2}{b(R)}$. (Source: Pugh's Real Mathematical Analysis: Chapter 1, Problem 26a)

Intuitively, it seems that the answer would be $4\pi$, as it seems that $s(R)$ (as $R$ grows large) would approximate $2\pi R$, while $b(R)$ would similarly approximate $\pi R^2$.

I have found the bound $\pi R^2 \leq b(R) \leq \pi (R + \sqrt{2})^2$, but have been unable to find a good way to accurately bound $s(R)$. My main line of attack has been to bound $s(R)$ as the area between some two circles, but this has not proven very successful. I have also tried to simply compute $s(R)$ by finding the number of unit squares per unit column and summing, but this devolves into a fairly messy computation.

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: What is the difference between a ball and a sphere?

Comment: Sphere is just the surface, ball is the surface and interior.

Comment: @NiyanthRao How is it possible? The cubes inside a ball of radius $R$ should be approximately equal to the volume of the sphere, which is $\frac{4}{3}\pi R^3$. Perhaps you work on $2$-dimensional space and you should change the words *ball, sphere* to *circle, circumference*.

Comment: Agreed with @NN2, it seems the question is phrased in 2-D. In 2-D, it seems then the limit should be $2\pi$. $s(R) \sim 2\pi R/\sqrt{2}$, and $b(R) \sim \pi R^2$.

Comment: @NN2 thanks, it’s meant to be in 2D space. Edited question to reflect that.

Comment: @LostStatistician18 that would be true if each square covered $\sqrt{2}$ of the circumference, but that seems rather unlikely (as for large $R$, the maximal amount possibly covered by each square is roughly $\sqrt{2}$)

Comment: @NiyanthRao, maybe I'm a little confused then about what you mean by "unit cubes intersecting". Two intepretations that make sense to me are 1) you essentially consider the minimal number of disjoint unit cubes required to cover each set, or 2) you are considering the "unit cubes" that you get from the standard unit cube tessellation of $\mathbb{R}^2$. I'm imagining now you are considering 1), but it is not clear which is which. I recommend adding some clarity on that point.

Comment: @LostStatistician18 I actually mean (2), not (1), my bad! Edited question again, sorry for all the errors in my initial post.

Answer (score 0):

This is not rigorous, and may be flawed, but my idea is that $s(R)$, the number of unit squares is equal to the combined area of those squares; so we can bound the area (which is easier). The maximum distance from the origin, that a point on a square which intersects the circle can have is $R+\sqrt{2}$, and the minimum distance is $R-\sqrt{2}$. So we can bound $s(R)$ using the area of the 2-D doughnut with inner radius $R$ and thickness $\pm\sqrt{2}$, so:

$$
\pi R^2-\pi(R-\sqrt{2})^2\leq s(R)\leq \pi(R+\sqrt{2})^2-\pi R^2
$$

If I didn't mess up the limit calculation, then the limit $[\lim_{R\rightarrow\infty}\frac{s(R)^2}{b(R)}]$ is bounded above and below by $8\pi$